# Python missing 1 required positional argument (Discord Bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello I am working on an autoreply bot feature which will reply to a certain phrase in a certain server, this is used by using the `c` argument alongside the `message` argument which is used to send the channel

If I did something wrong or did not provide enough information please tell me

Here is my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

class Listener(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, c, message):
        if (c.guild):
            if c.guild.name == "Server Name goes here":
                if message.content.find("Hello There") != -1:
                    await message.channel.send("General Kenobi")

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Listener(bot))
```

The error:

```
Bot Online!
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Documents/Bots/DS BOT/bot.py", line 91, in <module>
    bot.run(token, bot=False)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 637, in run
    _cleanup_loop(loop)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 92, in _cleanup_loop
    _cancel_tasks(loop)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 77, in _cancel_tasks
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 603, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 316, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1823, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 430, in select
    self._poll(timeout)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 779, in _poll
    status = _overlapped.GetQueuedCompletionStatus(self._iocp, ms)
```

Comment: I am sorry if I did not provide the correct sentence structure

Comment: It's not about the "correct sentence structure", it's about asking a question and providing enough information. You now only added one line of the error message instead of the full stacktrace. The stacktrace would provide us (and yourself!) a clue to where the problem is, making it an important detail to add. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to learn more about it.

Comment: I am sorry I will provide the full stack of the error

Comment: No need to apologize. I'm just helping you to improve your question. Thanks for updating the question!

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow so thanks for showing me the ropes

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the [Discord API documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message), the `on_message()` function should have only one argument.

If you implement the function as a class method you'll need to start with the parameter `self`, so it should have two arguments in total. Your version has three arguments, which is one too many. So when the function is called, Python will say there is a missing argument.

It's not clear to me what the `c` variable in your code is. Depending on how you create that variable, you should probably store it the `Listener` object like this:

```py
from discord.ext import commands


class Listener(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot, c):  # <-- added here
        self.bot = bot
        self.c = c  # <-- store it in the Listener object

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):  # <-- using 2 arguments!
        if self.c.guild:  # <-- using self.c instead of c
            if self.c.guild.name == "Server Name goes here":
                if message.content.find("Hello There") != -1:
                    await message.channel.send("General Kenobi")

def setup(bot):
    # c = whatever this is supposed to be...
    bot.add_cog(Listener(bot, c))
```

Note that I've no personal experience with discord.py so I'm not sure if this is working, but this is a common pattern and solves the "number of arguments" problem.

Comment: I am aware of this, but if I do as you said I get the error: `TypeError: on_message() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`      (I only included the `self` argument)

Comment: If you only include the `self` argument, you'll have 1 argument. The code in your question has 3 arguments. There should be 2 arguments!

Comment: yes, but since I want to isolate the bot to a specific server which requires the need of the `c` argument

Comment: Then you should probably give that `c` parameter as argument to the `__init__` method of your class and store it in the class object. I'll try to provide an example later if I have the time.

Comment: I am unable to do that because `__init__()` is missing 1 required positional argument: `c`. This is the error I get

Comment: @DanA, I've updated my answer. Since I don't know what `c` is in your code, I couldn't provide a better answer. If you update your question to include enough information, I might take another look at it and see if i can improve my answer as well. Or maybe this answer will already guide you in the right direction.

Comment: The `c` parameter is the `content` of the message being sent, in this context, it is used to present the server name

Comment: you can look at the Discord.py documentation https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.guild.id == server id here:
            if message.content.find("Hello There") != -1:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                await message.channel.send("General Kenobi")
```